# Can Rcpp do automatic bounds checking?

Tags: rcpp

In C++, if using `vector` types from the STL, some compilers such as GCC have compilation options like `_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS` which will force it to add bound checks for vectors in debug builds, so that if I try to access an element at a position longer than the vector, it will result in an error.

RcppArmadillo has a similar debug macro that can be turned on for bounds checking.

Does Rcpp have something similar for classes like `Rcpp::NumericVector` or `Rcpp::IntegerVector`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does:

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("IntegerVector foo(IntegerVector v) { v.at(11) = 42L; \
                     return v; }")
> foo( 1:10 )
Error in foo(1:10) : Index out of bounds: [index=11; extent=10].
>
```

You can also consider RcppArmadillo where Armadillo has the checks on by default with ability to disable:

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("arma::vec foo(arma::vec v) { v(11) = 42L; \
                     return v; }", depends="RcppArmadillo")
> foo( 1:10 )
Error in foo(1:10) : Mat::operator(): index out of bounds
>
```

Comment: But for that you had to use `.at()`, while `_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS` can turn it on for `operator[]` too. Would there be an option or a `#define` for that?